# convert date format in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I would like to know how to convert 2015-06-15 to June 15, 2015 in PHP
This is essentially the format that it is stored as in mysql, and in how I retrieve it:

```
$crs_date1 = $row_crs['course_date1'];
```

then echo it:

```
echo $crs_date1
```

but I would rather echo it in a more readable format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not trying to change the ordering of the format, but rather change the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo strftime("%B %m, %Y", strtotime($crs_date1));
```

Might give you an error (this was just off the top of my head), so the format (first parameter of `strftime`) could be  a bit wrong

Comment: Full month is `F`. `B` is swatch internet time.

Comment: what would be %B stand for? thanks in advance. what changes should i make based on your recent comment

Comment: %B Full month name, based on the locale January through December

list of all things you can add there : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo date('F m Y',strtotime($crs_date1));
```